# Why do I get $E[Y^2] > 0$ with one approach but $E[Y^2] = 0$ with another approach for $Y|X \sim N(0,\sigma_X^2)$?

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose $Y|X \sim N(0,\sigma_X^2)$ where $\sigma_X^2$ is the variance of $X$. Does this mean $Y$ itself has a normal distribution? Because it seems like this would cause a problem. If $Y$ has a normal distribution, $Y^2$ will have a $\chi^2$ distribution which means that $E[Y^2] > 0$. But we also have
\begin{align*}
E[Y^2] &= E[E[Y^2|X]] \\
&= E[Y E[Y|X]] \\
&= E[Y \cdot 0] \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
So is $Y$ normally distributed if $Y|X \sim N(0,\sigma_X^2)$? If so, why have I got conflicting results for the mean of $Y^2$? Did I make a mistake?

Comment: I don't think you can justify the second equality - you can't take $Y$ out of the conditional expectation like that.

Comment: I thought this is allowed because of the 'pull-out' property of conditional expectation?

Comment: You can pull out $X$, or a function of $X$, but not $Y$ I don't think

Comment: $\mathbb E[Y^2]>0$ unless $Y$ is almost surely equal to zero. The notation $\sigma_X$ is confusing as it seems to indicate the conditional variance depends on the realisation of $X$, while the sentence "$σ^2_X$ is the variance of $X$" seems to indicate a fixed variance whatever the realisation of $X$ in which case $Y$ is also marginally Normal.

Comment: @csss I don't know exactly what "pull out property" you're referring to, but the second line is definitely not true.

Comment: The second equality ought to be $E(\sigma^2_X)$. Now as pointed out by @Xi'an, if $\sigma^2_X$ is variance of $X$ it is a constant and variance of $Y$ is simply $\sigma^2_X$. If not, you'd need to know the function to get the marginal.